# MQ vs REST Performance in Multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, rest, mq

Currently I have a messaging engine that processes thousands of requests per second, the performance is bad because the current implementation is consuming a REST service which is a blocking operation, so it ends up running out of threads from the thread pool, since consuming a REST service is running on top of HTTP what I understand is that there is no way for me to fire a "fire and forget" request, at least I need to wait for the HTTP Response, even if a Future is used this would be running in a different thread, so even if the main thread is not blocked it will end up starving the thread pool anyway, so my question is, if I have this high number of concurrency wouldn't it be better to send this to an MQ instead? this way this wouldn't be a blocking operation anymore, correct ? The app is currently running on Akka framework.

Comment: As far as I understood your issue is that your message engine is conntecting to a HTTP server to retrieve new messages, one by one? Could you download a batch of messages and split them later on to reduce the number of requests issued? If you only retrieve via `GET` [pipelining requests](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-6.3.2) using the same connection could be an option as well. You might increase throughput by scaling broad. Whether a MQ based system achives higher throughput is debateble - it might, it might not. As you see there are many options you can look into.

Comment: Hi Roman, thank you for your reply, we are doing a POST request to an HTTP API in order to send a push notification, but the issue is that this POST request is taking more than 1 sec, hence it is blocking our threads

Comment: If you will send messages to MQ in one thread faster than other thread will get them from queue and execute http call you will either run out of memory or periodically block main thread to allow consumer to keep up

Comment: You need to use asynchronous I/O - it can be either upon HTTP or MQ, no difference.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov, hi Alex, can this issue be solved only with a reactive API? or which kind of asynchronous I/O you mean ? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So the initial data are as follows:

- your program issues thousands of requests per second to a REST service,
- POST request is taking more than 1 sec,
- it ends up running out of threads from the thread pool.

First thing you should check: how many simultaneous requests the REST service is able to bear? Can it be so that it cannot handle thousands of requests per second, and the large timing of single request is a result of the service overloading? Then you have to set a mechanism to limit the rate of your requests. Actually, to set such a limit is a good idea under all circumstances.

Second, you should decide if such access rate can be achieved with synchronous or asynchronous I/O. Synchronous I/O is simpler and faster, but requires more memory consumption for threads. A rough estimate is as follows:

- less than 100 simultaneous requests: use sync
- more than 10000 simultaneous requests: use async
- in between: either way

If you decided to use synchronous I/O, then the most simple and natural way to set a request rate limit is using a Semaphore: a thread wanting to issue next requests acquires the semaphore object, and after recieving the reply releases it. Keep the number of threads in thread pool equal to the request limit.

If you decided to use asynchronous I/O, then there is no universal mechanism to set such a limit, because asynchronous semaphores usually are not available for developer. If your async I/O library has reactive interface, use it (async semaphores are part of backpressure mechanism). If not, you can create such a mechanism out of following components:

- a blocking queue for asynchronous requests
- a limiting Semaphore
- a thread, which in a loop does the following: acquires the semaphore, takes next request from the queue, and issues it. When the request is finished (no matter successfully or not), the semaphore is released by the request's callback.

This mechanism uses single thread for all the asynchronous requests, thus consuming not so much memory, and works fast enough. If, however, you need it to work faster, simply increase the number of threads.